# Formula parse error with Sheets array literal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image]

I'm trying to follow https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276 to put a column header in U3 with a formula in the cell below it. I have:

```
=ArrayFormula({'HI';  if(Today()-V4:V=today(),"no",Today()-V4:V);})
```

But I'm getting a 'Formula Parse error' . How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula({"HI";if(Today()-V4:V=today(),"no",Today()-V4:V)})
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified that to =ArrayFormula({"days_since_contact";IFERROR(if(Today()-V$4:V=today(),"",round(Today()-V$4:V)),"")})